# How can I take multiple inputs from a user and convert to a string that looks up values and adds them to a variable?

Tags: shell-script, shell, user-input

I have a script that takes input from a user (options 1, 2, 3, etc.) to choose files to deploy to a remote server. Instead of the user running this script multiple times, I would like for them to be able to input multiple options (ex. 2,3) and as a result, those entries would add text to a variable that is then referenced in the main function.

I have tried summing these and having input match the sum, however, if we have many artifacts to put in this list, option 5 would deploy one thing and options 2,3 would deploy differently, but added together would deploy the same as option 5 which is not acceptable.

For instance this is what I have currently setup I am just matching the string input from the user (after dropping spaces, if any) and running that option. This is OK for only 2 or 3 artifacts, however, when the list gets long the choices get exponentially greater.

```
#!/bin/sh

export alltags="all"
export tag1="artifact1"
export tag2="artifact2"
export tag3="artifact3"

deployment_tag=""

function updateArtifacts

{
   cp -r /path/to/artifact/artifact.zip --tags "\"${deployment_tag}"\"
}

echo "Enter the number of the artifacts you would like to deploy"
"1. artifact1"
"2. artifact2"
"3. artifact3"

read -p " " num

trimNum=`echo $num | sed 's/ //g'`

if [ "$trimNum" == "1" ]; then
       $deployment_tag+="$alltags"
       echo "Updating all artifacts"
       updateArtifacts
elif [ "$trimNum" == "2" ]; then
       $deployment_tag+="$tag1"
       echo "Updating artifact 1"
       updateArtifacts
elif [ "$trimNum" == "2,3" ]; then
       $deployment_tag+="$tag1,$tag2"
       echo "Updating artifact 1 and 2"
       updateArtifacts
else
     echo "aborted, please enter a valid selection"
fi
```

I know I am missing options, but this is just to give a brief example.  I know this is long winded, I appreciate any input.

Comment: Why would you break the script's flow and ask the user to manually enter data instead of just passing the options as argument at run time? This makes your script much harder to use, more error prone and much harder to automate. Also, what shell are you using? `==` is not standard in `[ ]`, it will work in bash but not in sh for example.

Comment: I am using sh, but it seems to work fine.  I'm not asking the user to input at runtime because ultimately there will be 10-15 artifacts in this list and it's easier for them to select from an available list.

Comment: if you're comparing the same variable against multiple values, it's better to use `case...esac` rather than `if/elif/elif/fi`.   e.g. `case "$trimNum" in 1) deployment_tag+="$tag1"; ... ;; 2) .... ;; 3) .... ;; esac` (**note the absence of $ before deployment_tag**. You're assigning the var, not using it).   Also, adding to @terdon's advice I suggest only prompting for the artifact number if it hasn't been provided as an argument.   That will make testing and using the script much easier.

Comment: trimNum should be split into an array, you can then iterate over the elements of the array with a case statement.

Comment: I was using case...esac in version 1 of this script but it wasn't allowing for matching the string being 2,3 for example.

Basically what I want to do here, is if a user chooses 2,3 for example, I don't want to have to have a selection for each combination.  I'd like for it to just add "tag2" and "tag3" to deployment_tags so I would end up with --tags "tag1,tag2".

Comment: that's why i said split it into an array and then iterate over the array elements, so you only have to append the appropriate tag for each individual case not for all the combinations.  each array element will be one (and only one) tag.

Comment: Ok great, I'll check into that.  My green may be showing here, but would you have an example of this?

Comment: not right now, i was just about to go to bed (it's 1am here in .au).

Comment: So you are using a system whose `/bin/sh` is a symlink to `/bin/bash`. This is very much not portable. I don't know if that is a problem for you, but to be on the safe side, you might want to change to the standard and portable `if [ "$trimNum" = "1" ]`.

Comment: Thanks for the info terdon.  I'll make this change.

Comment: I was able to add trimNum as an array, however, its taking the user input as the "deployment_tag".  For example, if I input "2,3" I get the output of --tags "2,3".

Any idea how I could allow the array to lookup the input of 2 to map to tag2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is an example of how to do this using arrays, and optionally taking args from the command line.  If no args were provided, prompt for the artifact tags instead.

I didn't end up using a `case` statement because it turned out that by putting all the tags into an array, it wasn't needed.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# dup stdout so we can print prompts etc in the ask function
# anything printed to >&3 will go to the terminal (i.e. original stdout)
# anything printed to stdout will be part of the function's return value
exec 3>&1

tags=( all
artifact1  artifact2  artifact3
artifact4  artifact5  artifact6
artifact7  artifact8  artifact9
artifact10 artifact11 artifact12
artifact13 artifact14 artifact15
)
declare -a deployment_tags
declare -a nums

# comment out or set to zero to disable debugging
debug=1

[ "$debug" = 1 ] && declare -p tags deployment_tags nums

###
### functions
###

print_choices() {
  i=1
  while [ "$i" -lt "${#tags[@]}" ] ; do
    # one per line
    #printf '%i. %s\n' "$i" "${tags[$i]}" >&3
    #let i=i+1

    # or three per line
    for j in 0 1 2; do
      [ -n "${tags[$i]}" ] && printf '%2i. %-12s\t' "$i" "${tags[$i]}" >&3
      let i=i+1
    done
    printf "\n" >&3

  done
}

usage() {
   echo "Usage: $(basename "$0") [n...]"
   echo
   print_choices
   echo "Choose 1 or more, separated by spaces or commas, or 0 for all of the above"
   exit 1;
}

ask() {
  echo "Enter the number of the artifacts you would like to deploy:" >&3
  print_choices
  echo "Choose 1 or more, separated by spaces or commas, 0 for all, or q to quit" >&3

  until [[ "$num" =~ ^[[:space:]0-9,qQ]+$ ]] ; do
    read -r -p "Choose: " num >&3

    [[ $num =~ [qQ] ]] && return 1

    # split into nums array.  if num contains zero ("all"), remove
    # all other choices as they're already included in "all"
    nums=( $(printf '%s' "$num" | sed -e 's/.*0.*/0/; s/,/ /g') )

    # if any of the numbers provided didn't correspond to a valid
    # tag, ask again
    for i in "${nums[@]}" ; do
      [ -z "${tags[$i]}" ] && echo "Invalid choice $i" >&3 && num=""
    done
  done

  echo "${nums[@]}"
}

updateArtifacts() {
   # WTF is the `--tags` argument to `cp`???
   # echo it because it's bogus
   echo cp -r /path/to/artifact/artifact.zip --tags "$@"

  # this function should do something useful with "$@".
}

###
### main code
###

# get the args from the command line, or ask for them if missing.
if [ -n "$*" ] ; then
  # only digits separated by commas or spaces allowed
  [[ "$*" =~ ^[[:space:]0-9,]+$ ]] || usage

  # split into nums array.  if num contains zero ("all"), remove
  # all other choices as they're already included in "all"
  nums=( $(printf '%s' "$*" | sed -e 's/.*0.*/0/; s/,/ /g') )
else
  nums=( $(ask) )
  [ "$?" != 0 ] && echo "Quitting..." && exit 0
fi

[ "$debug" = 1 ] && declare -p nums

# get nums choices into deployment_tags array
for i in "${nums[@]}" ; do
  [ -z "${tags[$i]}" ] && echo "Error: tag $i does not exist!" && exit 2

  deployment_tags+=("${tags[$i]}")
done

[ "$debug" = 1 ] && declare -p deployment_tags

updateArtifacts "${deployment_tags[@]}"
```

Comment: # WTF is the `--tags` argument to `cp`???

This is great. My apologies, in my haste I copied the wrong command.  The command is not for cp but instead for an Ansible playbook.

Comment: This is excellent though.  Thank you very much for this cas!

Comment: One last question.  If I need the comma to persist in the --tags "" section, such as --tags "artifact1, artifact2", would that be possible?  I've tried to edit this script to include, but I can only get it to add the comma at the beginning or the end.

Comment: convert it back to commas.  e.g. with something like `$(echo "{deployment_tags[*]}" | sed -E 's/ +/,/g')`.   Note the `[*]` to return a single space-separated string with all array elements instead of `[@]` to return one string per element.   of course, this won't work if any of the elements contain spaces.   so use `$(printf '%s,' "${deployment_tags[@]}" | sed -e 's/,$//')` instead....sort of a quick-and-dirty join() function.

Comment: Fantastic.  Thanks again, you're a lifesaver.

Comment: The original answer you provided above is working great, however, when I incorporate the $(printf '%s,' "${deployment_tags[@]}" | sed -e 's/,$//') portion, it doesn't work with the ansible playbook command as it doesn't seem to pass the tag outside of this script.  The tag prints correctly in echo, but it doesn't seem to work when running the actual updateArtifacts function.  Any idea of how I can fix that?

Comment: @oakenshield this is the first time that ansible has been mentioned.  you should post a new question (with a minimal example that demonstrates the problem)

Comment: Right, I thought I had mentioned I accidentally put the cp command being used in the function instead of ansible-playbook.  Will post a new question - thanks.